# Does the expression "were crazy for" make any sense in this text?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Yesterday we was to my niece's wedding party and all the girls were crazy for one of the waiters. And I myself have to agree that he was a very good looking guy.

Comment: What doesn't make sense in your sentence is *yesterday we* ***was to***.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Michael. That was great.

Comment: Thanks, Jason. Now I can see it's wrong. I should have used "we were" instead.

Comment: @Itamar Actually, that should be "we went to" not "we were to" or "we was to" although I **think** "we were to" is used in VERY informal BrE. In AmE, it would be taken as a clear error.

Comment: Nice tip, David. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @David Siegel - "I think "we were to" is used in VERY informal BrE." (for "we went to) - Not anywhere in Britain that I know of.

Comment: In fact, in AmE, you hear: ***We were over to their house***. But, don't worry about that very regional usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider "crazy for" to mean "very enthusiastic about". We often say that people are "crazy" or "mad" about, or for, something or someone. Figuratively a comparison is being made, perhaps, with obsessive mental illness, although 'crazy about/for' used this way does not imply any abnormality.

> Crazy
>
> 2 Extremely enthusiastic.
>
> ‘I'm crazy about Cindy’

[Crazy](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/crazy)

Comment: Thanks for the awesome explanation, Michael.